# Correct possessive: "my genius" or "my ingeniosity"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, possessives, uncountable-nouns

I have stumbled across the usage of "genius" as a possessive on two seperate occassions:

A meme featuring Jeremy Clarkson from Top Gear saying:

> Sometimes my **genius** is... it's almost frighting

Critertion (i) from the UNESCO World Heritage Site:

> "to represent a masterpiece of human creative **genius**"

I feel however that the usage of "genius" as a possessive here is a bit awkward and that the correct word should be "ingeniosity". Am I correct?

Comment: I would be inclined to use "ingeniousness".

Comment: This is the first time I've ever seen ingeniosity, so I think you'd be better of with "ingenuity" or, as @HotLicks said, "ingeniousness".

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with “my genius.”

Comment: @Xanne though you do say so yourself!